# How do I use Angular view templates in Trigger.io app with local template files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, trigger.io

I want to create separate template files to keep my HTML clean and modular. Angular is unable to pull in local files for usage as a template.

For example I have a file at `src/views/test.html`, and my `src/js/main.js` looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('test', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngTouch'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'TestController',
    templateURL: 'views/test.html'

  $routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $routeParams) {});
```

But the app doesn't work and the template HTML is not pulled in.

I tried playing around with `forge.file.getLocal` and `forge.file.string` but the seem incompatible with `template` option of `$routeProvider.when` because they are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was a capitalization problem. **You MUST use `templateUrl`, not `templateURL`, for the Angular JS router to work.**

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `../views/test.html` instead of `views/test.html` as the template url.

The reason could be because of your directory structure.  It looks like your directory structure is this:

```
src/

   js/
     main.js

   views/
     test.html
```

I think because `main.js` and `test.html` are at the same directory level, but in different folders, `main.js` doesn't know of the `views` folder.

Also, it might make your life easier if you put your main angular app in a directory "above" the rest of your angular js code like so:

```
src/
  main.js

  js/
    controllers.js
    services.js
    .
    .
    .

  views/
    test.html
```

When you get more familiar with angular, you should check out [ng-boilerplate](http://joshdmiller.github.io/ng-boilerplate/#/home) on Github.  It's a repo/project that shows you how to set up and structure Angular code in a very clean and efficient way.